# Spacer gif replaced by png, can't find the img anywhere so I can replace it. What's going on here?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website http://www.eluminatecreative.com/new/index.html and where it says "sum'r fling" I need to replace it with another img but I can't find it anywhere and I can't replace the spacer img with an image and have it work the same. What is causing this and how can I replace it? Is this some kind of jQuery code I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the class attached to the spacer `<img>`

```
<img src="images/spacer.gif" width="405" height="52" alt="" class="myimage">
```

If you look at the corresponding CSS:

```
.yellow_li:hover .myimage {
    background:url(../images/summr.png) repeat-y center bottom;
}
```

So, replace this image: `http://www.eluminatecreative.com/images/summr.png`

Comment: Wow! I checked and checked and couldn't find it anywhere. Found out the image just didn't upload, that's what was tripping me up. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Firefox, you should get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). If you're using Chrome, you should learn how to use the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview).